# What determines the alignment snapping in NetBeans GUI Builder?

Tags: java, netbeans, alignment, layout-manager, gui-builder

I'm perplexed by the "snapping" behavior of NetBeans GUI Builder - those dotted lines (and the magnetic force they exert) as I move components about within a container.  Is it determined by the Layout Manager?  Or by container properties such as Insets?  I wouldn't have expected the Absolute Layout to have any "preference" about alignment, yet even *it* seems to have some notion of a "grid" toward which it pulls my components.  How or where does one change this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a work around to do this.

If you do...

```
...setLayout(null);
```

Then you will reduce the snapping to 10 by 10 pixels.

If you want to get better than that, you have to do something like this:

http://forums.netbeans.org/post-37209.html

Comment: Did you happen to see the last post in that Netbeans forum thread you linked to?  (netero)  I may be misunderstanding the intent, but it doesn't look like he's talking about *layout* at all - would you agree?  (Apart from that, it looks like the answer is that if you want more precision than what snapping gives, you have to specify X and Y positioning in the Layout section of Properties)